# Chaining controller actions in sails JS - actions 2 format

Tags: sails.js

I'm attempting to chain together a couple of controller actions in the newer actions 2 format in Sails JS. I cannot get them both to fire.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
// config/routes.js

'POST /api/v1/slack/slash': [ 
      { action: 'slack/slash/action1', csrf: false },
      { action: 'slack/slash/action2', csrf: false }
    ],
```

The format above returns a 404.

I've also tried this:

```js
'POST /api/v1/slack/slash': [ 'slack/slash/action1', 'slack/slash/action2' ],
```

In this format the first action runs, but not the 2nd. Also, I then have to disable CSRF for the entire app instead of just that route.

I can only find documentation on how to do this in the old actions1 format.

Anyone know?

Comment: Maybe you should use helpers instead of trying to chain actions. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers

Answer (score 0):

You might require to use Policies instead:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies

Check the section `Policy ordering and precedence`:

You could define:

```js
// config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {
 'path/to-controller/*': ['policy-one', 'policy-two']
}
```

And in your policies:

```js
// api/policies/policy-one

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  // First process
  next();
}
```

The second one:

```js
// api/policies/second-one

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  // Second process
  next();
}
```

For that, you need to define a route and a controller endpoint.

```js
module.exports.routes = {
  'POST /api/v1/slack/slash': { action: 'slack/slash' }
  // action2 controller: api/controllers/slack/slash.js
}
```

And the controller:

```js
// api/controllers/slack/slash.js

module.exports = {
  inputs: { /* ... */},
  exits:  { /* ... */},
  fn: function (/*inputs, exits, env*/) {
    return 'Hello world'
  }
}
```